# Is it possible to combine SharePoint with .net 4 code

Tags: c#, sharepoint, entity-framework

We are designing a system.

We would like to use SharePoint webparts which are .net framework 3.5 as the UI. We also have some access to the database which we would like to use EF4 which is framework 4.

Is this possible? Or do we need to put as web service hop in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time, no version of SharePoint is compatible with .Net 4. 
An explanation can be found here: http://mossblogger.blogspot.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-and-net-4-confused.html

So, yes - you have to put an extra layer between your UI layer and the DB layer.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint webparts come in two types, the ASP.NET ones and the actual SharePoint ones. Most web parts should be built using the ASP.NET base class. Which means you can build a stand alone ASP.NET application with those web parts (dont need sharepoint to host them).

But if you must use sharepoint as the front-end, then yes having a good SOA (web service) is better than trying to merge all the functionality together into sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 3.5 as from SP1 supports Entity Framework 4

Answer (score -1):

This website shows what you have to do to integrate [SharePoint – The MOSS](http://skurocks.wordpress.com/2009/04/21/net-40-%E2%80%93-part-1/)

Comment: The link has nothing to do with Sharepoint 2010. It just talks about new features in .NET 4.